# Open a new page when marker clicked on map [Android Studio]

Tags: android, kotlin, maps

I'm making an Android app on Android Studio (`Kotlin`) where I have some markers placed on my `Google Map` and I am confused on how to open a new `page/activity` when a maker is clicked for more information.

I am aware I need to use an `OnClick` function but I am confused on how to implement it.

I'm just starting out on `Android Studio`, so I have been struggling with where to start.

Comment: there is a onMarkerClick() callback use it to open another Activity

Comment: What do you mean by callback?

Answer (score 1):

Here how can you use that in Kotlin

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
    // Your implementation
    true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMap has setOnMarkerClickListener interface which has onMarkerClick callback. From there you can call new activity.

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        // Call your activity here

    }
});
```